# Why my request works locally and does not on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rest-client

I'm running `rake send_events` locally and `heroku run rake send_events` on heroku.

```
values = {sendSmsRequest:
              {
                  from: "ABC",
                  to: "5581999999999",
                  msg: "msg",
                  callbackOption: "NONE",
                  id: "c_1541"
              }
}
headers = {
    :content_type => 'application/json',
    :authorization => 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    :accept => 'application/json'
}


RestClient.post 'https://api-rest.zenvia360.com.br/services/send-sms', values.to_json, headers
```

The log print
[RestClient::Exceptions::OpenTimeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24oB3.png)

Thanks.

Comment: DId you fix this problem? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`OpenTimeout` means that rest-client timed out trying to open a connection to the server.

Are you sure that the server is up and reachable from heroku? I'm not able to reach it from my computer or any server that I tried with.

```
$ nc -w 10 -v api-rest.zenvia360.com.br 443
nc: connect to api-rest.zenvia360.com.br port 443 (tcp) timed out
```